# MAAS: How to create / update a network interface for a new machine using CLI / API?

Tags: maas

I was able to create a new machine using the MAAS API. The problem is, that there is the need to add / change the interface before commissioning which does not work.

### Try 1: No mac_address during machine creation

Created a machine without specifying the mac address.  This leaves the interface section of the machine completely empty.

The command

```
maas myreg interfaces create-physical <system_id> name=eno1 mac_address="fc:aa:64:1f:0f:1c"
```

fails with:

```
Cannot create interface because the machine is not Ready, Allocated, or Broken.
```

### Try 2: Specify mac_address during machine creation

Created a machine specifying the mac_addresses parameter adds an interface to the machine, but the interface has everything set to default and therefore cannot be used directly. But changing does not work, like:

```
maas myreg interface update ....
maas myreg interface link-subnet ....
```

all end with mostly the same error message:

```
Cannot link subnet interface because the machine is not Ready, Allocated, or Broken.
```

### Observations

Using the GUI I was able to change / add the interface as needed.

### Question

I need to change / update / add interface when the machine is in 'New' state. How can this be done?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Annoyingly, I have found a workaround for this. You can set a DHCP snippet to set the DHCP IP, but you also need to set it in MaaS as it overrides it after commission

Answer (score 0):

So I've done this before.  I'm assuming 'new machine' is a VM, if so, you can follow this template. You'll want to follow the steps shown below with the number of interfaces needed at creation time.

- Can you add interfaces after the VM has been created?  No, not to my knowledge.
- Can you add interfaces for physical machines after identified?  Yes, but you'll need to commission the server again.

In the example below, I used the following settings:

- vCPU: 4,
- RAM_in_MB: 4096,
- HDD1: 60,
- Internal_CIDR": "192.168.1.0/24",
- public_cidr: "10.245.1.0/24"

Create a VM:

```
vm-host compose {pod_id} cores={vCPU} memory={RAM_in_MB} 'storage=mylabel:{HDD1},mylabel:{HDD2}' interfaces='eno1:subnet_cidr={Internal_CIDR};eno2:subnet_cidr={public_cidr}'
```

If you need a bridge:

```
interfaces create-bridge {server_id} name=br0 parent={interface_id} bridge_stp=True
```

Set IP:

```
interface link-subnet {server_id} {interface} subnet={cidr} mode=STATIC ip_address={vm_ip}"
```

Deploy:

```
machine deploy {server_id} distro_series="focal hwe_kernel=hwe-20.04"
```